# What if I have less control tasks than I need to mix all suites for workers in toloka

Tags: crowdsourcing, toloka

For example I have 5 control tasks and 100 tasks and have mixing settings 4 task and 1 control.
What happens when the worker (aka toloker) just seen the last one, while there are still more potential task suites to work on?

Answer (score 1):

**The worker be kicked out of the "pool"** !So only 5 task for every worker!

If the worker has seen all of the control tasks in the pool, he will not be able to complete any more of the task suits and will be notified that the tasks are finished.
However, if you create a separate pool with the exact same control tasks, the system will consider those as new control tasks and can show them to the same tolokers (But it could affect quality) I suggest create more control tasks from verified answers from prev runs